# Laravel Homestead - Setting Meilisearch to a previous version

Tags: laravel, homestead, meilisearch

I recently installed the app I've been working on on a different machine. This machine is now using a newer version of homestead, which consequently forces me to use a newer version of Meilisearch.

So if I type in this command, for example:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/projects/project$ meilisearch
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Expected Meilisearch engine version: 0.20.0, current engine version: 0.28.1. To update Meilisearch use a dump.
```

And if I try to use Meilisearch in my app, I get the following error:

```
Json deserialize error: unknown field `filters`, expected one of `q`, `offset`, `limit`, `attributesToRetrieve`, `attributesToCrop`, `cropLength`, `attributesToHighlight`, `showMatchesPosition`, `filter`, `sort`, `facets`, `highlightPreTag`, `highlightPostTag`, `cropMarker` at line 1 column 29
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no explanation in the docs to set the version, so you have to use the latest. The first error indicates you are trying to launch Meilisearch with an older database (`data.ms`). Until v1.0, Meilisearch versions are not compatible with each other. Hence, to resolve the error, delete the older/existing database folder (`data.ms`) and relaunch the instance. The second error indicates that your code or SDK is incompatible with Meilisearch. As a best practice, it is recommended to review the version compatibility of Meilisearch and your app in the changelogs. You would need to update your code to fix the error.